# how to put necessary xml files required by the application while creating exe through install shield?

Tags: wpf

I was creating .exe file via install sheild for my wpf application but at a point where we need to put the project output files I got confused.I want to add xml files considering the fact that it should point to local reference application bin/ debug folder.
How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.A walkthrough would be of great use.

Comment: this must help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ramin Sorry ur provided link do tell me abt the types of application data files but my question is in regards with install sheild.

Comment: See the 'Content' or 'Resource'. For example, if you want to send an xml file with your application, add it to the 'Solution', set its 'Build Action' to 'Content', and its 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy Always'. You can see the file in 'Debug' or 'Release' Directories.